# Textview in Android Widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I started with a widget and I'm trying to use a TextView in my Main.xml .So I just add one with drag and drop but I dont know how to find it with the code. In a normal Android Application I used

> TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

and then

> text.setText("Blabla");

But when I try it in a Widget I get a error that 'findViewById' is undefined for this type... Is there any alternative ? How do I have to declare it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a specific widget you're using?

Comment: I followed this turoial http://www.pocketpc.ch/android-entwicklung/149731-anleitung-digitaluhr-widget-programmieren.html its in german but google helps :D

Comment: Could you please post your stacktrace and maybe some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a widget you have to use RemoteViews. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

RemoteViews has several methods to set the values of the containing views, e.g. setTextViewText(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewText%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: ok but how can I give the ID ? so how the program knows which Textview Im mean ? (like findviewbyid)

Comment: You have to give it an ID in the layout you load. Even if you used drag and drop to put the view in the layout, there must be an editor somewhere where you can change the properties...